# How can I detect an empty string when I use a SearchView.setOnQueryTextListener

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-layout

I'm trying to filter a list every time the query text of a SearchView has changed.

`svComuni` is the name of the SearchView.

This is my code on my main activity:

```
private fun setUIControl() {
    binding.svComuni.setOnQueryTextListener(textChangeListener())

}

inner class textChangeListener: SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
    override fun onQueryTextSubmit(p0: String?): Boolean {
        return findAllSimilarCountry(p0)
    }

    override fun onQueryTextChange(p0: String?): Boolean {
        return findAllSimilarCountry(p0)
    }

}

private fun findAllSimilarCountry(p0: String?): Boolean {
    Log.d(TAG, p0!!)
    return true
}
```

By using this listener I'm able to detect every change in query text of SearchView when I insert some char and when I submit, but not in case I remove the last character. So the empty query text doesn't trigger the listener. How can I include this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you try to add validation to your listener methods? For example:

```
 if (p0.equals("")) {
        return false
     } else {
        return findAllSimilarCountry(p0)
     }
```